# Inserts with executemany and partialy parametrized lists

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sequence, cx-oracle

I'm trying to improve a batch service which inserts elements into a oracle database. Currently I'm having perfomance issues during the insert.

For now my insert string is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (:COL1, :COL2, :COL3);
```

Whereas the execution of the string is something like:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.executemany(sql, list)
```

Nothing unusual until here right?!

But MYTABLE has a PK column which is filled by a trigger (that finds out the PK out from a sequence table) on the insert execution. Notice that I will have several parallel processes executing the same inserts, everyone of them accessing the trigger thus the sequence table.

From my initial research I found out that I can drop the trigger and access the sequence table directly in the insert, and here is my problem, how can I write this insert string?

Stuff like this doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (MYTABLE_SQ.nextval, :COL1, :COL2, :COL3);
```

Neither does this (even with the column setted in the right order):

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (MYTABLE_SQ.nextval, :COL1, :COL2, :COL3);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full error message that you get ?  Oracle SQL allows to reference the sequence as you do in a INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

> access the sequence table directly

Firstly, you need to create the `SEQUENCE` object to refer it directly to get the `NEXTVAL` value. You cannot fetch it from a sequence table as you mentioned in your question. You **use a sequence to auto increment** rather than storing it in a table and fetch it. For `Pre 12c versions`, the `SEQUENCE +TRIGGER` is the right method.

I am not sure why you decided to drop the trigger at first place and trying to access sequence in the SQL. Because, your approach introduces another problem where you are trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col2, col3)
VALUES (sequence_name.NEXTVAL, :2, :3, :4)
```

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO table(id, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4)
```

The difference is that, instead of bind variable `:name` you are passing `sequence_name.NEXTVAL`. To avoid this, you could do it in this way:

```
cursor.execute("select sequence_name.NEXTVAL from dual")
seq_value, = cursor.fetchone() --> assign sequence value then pass as bind variable

INSERT INTO table(id, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (:seq_value, :2, :3, :4)
```

To avoid all these sequence related maintenance, if you are on `Oracle 12c` please use the `IDENTITY COLUMN`. See Oracle documentation for [Identity columns](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#CJABEJEF).

Comment: By "access the sequence table directly" I mean that I want to avoid the trigger, and only that.

Comment: Then as I have suggested, either you need to bind it or fetch it prior and pass as bind variable as shown in answer. What's your Oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick:

```
DECLARE
    ID NUMBER := MYTABLE_SQ.nextval;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (ID, COL1, COL2, COL3);
END;
```